# Smoothness of Product Functions

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$. Define
$$f(x,y)\equiv f_x(y)\equiv f_y(x)$$
If $f_x$ and $f_y$ are both smooth, is $f$ smooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well-known counterexample: $f=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$